# How to convert a std::set of strings to lowercase c++ using some combination of for_each, transform, iterators and lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, stl

I'm trying to convert a set of strings to lowercase without using low level loops like while and for(;;) because I'm practicing using the STL. I was thinking about using for_each and transform and lambda but I'm not really sure how they work.

```
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    set<string> words;
    //insert a bunch of words using words.insert().....
    //convert everything in words to lower case
    return 0;
}
```

How would I convert each string in the set `words` using any combination of for_each, transform, iterators and lambdas?

I was thinking of doing something like: `transform(words.begin(), words.end(), words.begin(), ??lambda??)` however I don't know how to do the 4th parameter

Comment: Don't use `transform` to insert into the same set you're reading from.  If that's really your goal, try `std::foreach`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do something like transform(words.begin(), words.end(), words.begin(), ??lambda??),
because words.begin() would be a const iterator.

You'll have to do something like this:

```
set<string> words;
set<string> new_words;
transform(words.begin(), words.end(), std::inserter(new_words, new_words.begin()), [](string s) {
        transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::tolower); 
        return s;
    });
return new_words;
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
     std::for_each(words.begin(),words.end(),[](char & c) { c = tolower(c); });
```

and include cctype.

Comment: `words` is a `set`